# KeyCloak server responds with IllegalArgumentException:An invalid control character was present in the cookie value or attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to deploy and test simple Spring Boot application with KeyCloak integration. I'm following this official tutorial: https://blog.keycloak.org/2017/05/easily-secure-your-spring-boot.html. But i'm getting an error "This page isn’t working" in browser (KeyCloak login page isn't shown) and KeyCloak throws this exception:

```
IllegalArgumentException:    An invalid control character was present in the 
cookie value or attribute
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.13.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <keycloak.version>3.3.0.Final</keycloak.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the exception log:

```
09:55:18,976 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-7) UT005071: Undertow 
req
uest failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /auth/ request {Accept= 
[text/html,applicatio
n/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8], Accept- 
Langu
age=[en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7], Cache-Control=[max-age=0], 
Accept-Enc
 oding=[gzip, deflate, br], User-Agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; 
x64)
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36], 
Conn
ection=[keep-alive], Cookie=[OAuth_Token_Request_State=2132636f-ed6a-44e2- 
915b-9
cefed4dc446; JSESSIONID=D0DA2ADDBE8F62E55C9F65EB71BE85A0], Referer= 
[http://local
host:8080/], Upgrade-Insecure-Requests=[1], Host=[localhost:8080]} response 
{Cac
he-Control=[no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, no-store], X-Powered- 
By=[Un
dertow/1], Server=[WildFly/11], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], X-Frame- 
Option s=[SAMEORIGIN], Content-Security-Policy=[frame-src 'self'; frame 
ancestors 
'self
'; object-src 'none';], Date=[Wed, 23 May 2018 03:55:18 GMT], Connection= 
[keep-a
live], X-Robots-Tag=[none], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], Content-Type= 
[text
/html;charset=utf-8], Content-Length=[2740]}}: 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentExceptio
 n: UT000173: An invalid control character [1087] was present in the cookie 
 value
 or attribute
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator(LegacyCookieSupp
  ort.java:142)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpToken(LegacyCookieSupport.
 java:163)
    at io.undertow.util.LegacyCookieSupport.adjustedCookieVersion(LegacyCook
 ieSupport.java:248)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.getCookieString(Connectors.java:154)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.flattenCookies(Connectors.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.processWrite(Htt
 pResponseConduit.java:161)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpResponseConduit.write(HttpRespon
 seConduit.java:596)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.write(Abstr
 actFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:106)
    at org.xnio.conduits.Conduits.writeFinalBasic(Conduits.java:132)
    at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.writeFinal(
  AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:175)
    at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(ConduitStreamSi
 nkChannel.java:104)
    at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.writeFinal(Detachabl
 eStreamSinkChannel.java:195)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.writeFinal
 (HttpServerExchange.java:2042)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.writeBufferBlocking(
 ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputS
 treamImpl.java:603)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter
 (HttpServletResponseImpl.java:479)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpSer
 vletResponseImpl.java:568)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest
  (ServletInitialHandler.java:339)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(Servlet
 InitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInit
 ialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInit
 ialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.cal
 l(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(Context
 ClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAct
 ion.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi
```

ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java 
      :
     1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi

ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi

ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
    1508)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi

ce$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:
    1508)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(Se
    rvletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(Servlet
    InitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(Se
    rvletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)

```
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:8
12)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If i clear browsing data keycloak will work but anyway after i deploy my app and click to 'My products'  i get the same exception again...

Any guesses?

Comment: Which version are you using? I cannot find the message in both Keycloak and Spring.

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA I'm using keycloak-3.3.0.Final and SpringBoot v.1.5.13.RELEASE

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown from `LegacyCookieSupport.isV0Separator()` or `LegacyCookieSupport.isHttpSeparator()` in Undertow.  You may have an invalid cookie. See also: https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/LegacyCookieSupport.java

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA Man, can i have your facebook or smth? I'm very new in auth stuff and never have used JBoss. Could it be because i'm connected to corporate network? Btw before i installed keycloak 3.3.0, i first installed keycloak 4.4.0.Beta and SpringBoot 2.2.0. And after i had the error i followed official doc and found out that in the tutorial they use keycloak-3.3.0 and SpringBoot 2 doesn't support keycloak adapter yet.

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace of the exception? If you have it, please edit your question and add(paste) it.

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA i added the exception

Comment: Ummmm... `An invalid control character [1087]` is char variable `п` but it is not included in `Cookie=[OAuth_Token_Request_State=2132636f-ed6a-44e2-915b-9cefed4dc446; JSESSIONID=D0DA2ADDBE8F62E55C9F65EB71BE85A0]`. I don't know the reason why the exception is thrown.

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA take look at my answer... Is it Keycloak bug or Spring boot bug or something wrong with my windows config?

Comment: Probably, Keycloak bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL! Solution was dumb... My PC name... My PC's name was Talgat-ПК. П and К are russian letters... After i renamed it to Talgat-PC everything starts to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

date region time setting may be wrong.You can set "-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US" to system variables